# jquery to prototype format question

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, facebox

I'm currently using the facebox_render plugin for rails, and am trying to get it working without jquery (so using prototype). I've got it 99% functional, but there's one line I'm having difficulty with.

how would I write the following using prototype?

```
link_to_function(name, "jQuery.facebox(function(){ #{remote_function(options)} })", html_options || options.delete(:html))
```

I'm not familiar with prototype, so chances are there's a really simple solution :P

It's the *jQuery.facebox(function() ... )* bit that's causing me grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) is a plugin that depends on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). That is, it depends on jQuery being loaded to work. To use Facebox, you need to load jQuery.

Try using the PrototypeJS port of Facebox, see: [Porting Facebox from jQuery to Prototype](http://blog.philburrows.com/articles/2008/05/05/porting-facebox-from-jquery-to-prototype/)

Comment: My question probably wasn't clear enough. I know that facebox depends on jquery. I already ported Facebox to prototype. What I'm looking for help doing is porting the Facebox_render_helper's "facebox_link_to" functionality from jquery to prototype